# Configure pam_mount to prompt for password

Tags: pam, cifs

I have configured my Ubuntu system to mount a cifs share using `pam_mount` and a credentials file (the credentials to access the cifs share are different to those I use on my Linux machine). I'd like to avoid having my password stored in plain text.

My setup is as follows: I enabled the following line in `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml`:

```
<luserconf name=".pam_mount.conf.xml" />
```

I added `cred` and `dir_mode` to the allowed `mntoptions`:

```
<mntoptions allow="nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other,cred,dir_mode" />
```

I've created a `~/.smbcredentials` file with the following contents and given it `0600` permissions:

```
domain=<MY_WIN_DOMAIN>
username=<MY_WIN_USERNAME>
password=<MY_WIN_PASSWORD>
```

I've created a `~/.pam_mount.conf.xml` file containing the cifs share I want to mount:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pam_mount>

<volume fstype="cifs" server="<MY_WIN_SERVER>" path="<MY_WIN_SERVER_SHARE>/<MY_WIN_SERVER_SHARE_SUBDIR>" mountpoint="/home/%(USER)/<MY_WIN_SERVER>" options="cred=/home/%(USER)/.smbcredentials,nosuid,nodev,dir_mode=0700" />

</pam_mount>
```

The above all works nicely. However, I don't like having my password stored in plain text. Is there a way to get some sort of password prompt instead?

Comment: An encrypted volume is not an option?

Comment: An encrypted volume might be an option - can you tell me a bit more about it or how it would work?